# Variable not seemed to be initialized

Tags: java, variables, initialization

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class finnTall {
  public static void main(String[]args){

    int antallTall;
    int antallLest;
    double nesteTall;
    double minsteVerdi;
    double nestMinsteVerdi;

    Scanner tast = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.println("Hvor mange tall?");
    antallTall = tast.nextInt();
    tast.nextLine();

    antallLest= 1;

    System.out.println("Skriv første tall: ");
    minsteVerdi = tast.nextDouble();
    tast.nextLine();

    for(antallLest=1;antallTall>antallLest;antallLest++){
      System.out.printf("Skriv %d. tall: ",antallLest+1);
      nesteTall = tast.nextDouble();
      tast.nextLine();

      if(nesteTall>minsteVerdi)
        nestMinsteVerdi=nesteTall;

      if(nesteTall<minsteVerdi)
        nesteTall = minsteVerdi;

      if(nesteTall>minsteVerdi && nesteTall<nestMinsteVerdi) 
      nestMinsteVerdi = nesteTall;   

    }

    System.out.printf("Minste verdien av tallene du har oppgitt er: %f\n",minsteVerdi);
    System.out.printf("Nest minste verdi av tallene du har oppgitt er: %f\n",nestMinsteVerdi);
    tast.close(); 
  }
}
```

It's a program supposed to calculate the lowest and second lowest number that the user provides.

For some reason, it says that the local variable `nestMinsteVerdi` is not initialized, and I can't seem to figure out why or where the fault is. I have been struggling with this for a good 2 hours.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

In Java, a local variable needs to have a definitely assigned value before its value is accessed.

You declare your local variable without assigning it a value. This is okay in Java, because the compiler will ensure that you give it a value before using it.

```
double nestMinsteVerdi;
```

Then set it if a condition is true:

```
if(nesteTall>minsteVerdi)
  nestMinsteVerdi=nesteTall;
```

Then access it in the conditional of an `if` statement. But if the condition above were *false*, the value of `nestMinisteVerdi` would not yet be assigned.

```
if(nesteTall>minsteVerdi && nesteTall<nestMinsteVerdi) 
   nestMinsteVerdi = nesteTall;
```

Since there's at least one way for the code to execute in which no value is assigned, the compiler complains. This is a *good* thing. Accidentally uninitialized variables can be a frequent source of defects.

From the Java Language Specification, [Chapter 16: Definite Assignment](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-16.html):

> The idea behind definite assignment is that an assignment to the local variable or blank final field must occur on every possible execution path to the access.

Comment: i get what you are saying, but at the same time i don't. What in the code needs change? im not seeing straight

Comment: You need to ensure that `nestMinsteVerdi` is given a value before you attempt to use it, regardless of which path through the code is taken during execution. One way to do that would be to provide a default value in its declaration - `double nestMinsteVerdi=0.0` (or whatever value is appropriate). Another would be an `else` case on `if(nesteTall>minsteVerdi)`.

Comment: @Bendik A third way would be to keep track of whether you've found a value for it and set it, say, by using a `boolean` flag variable, and not printing it out at the end if you never found a value to assign to it.

Comment: I used the changes to an else if, and also set nestMinsteVerdi to = 0. Still when running the program, the program reads the least smallest number as the last one typed in, and the smallest number as the first one typed in. No clue

Comment: Now you've moved on to a different question. :) Look at your `if` statements - what they're testing, and what they're setting. Also, you're going to need a default value that's not a value that the user can enter - for example, Double.NaN (and test for that with Double.isNaN). Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

Andy Thomas's answer is correct. You do not assign a value to the variable.

```
double nestMinsteVerdi;
```

The compiler will not allow you to run because the only assignment is within a conditional that could conceivably fail, and if it were to fail, the variable would not be assigned a value. Since code can't be compared to a variable with no value, this would break execution, so the compiler will not allow it.